# Can't update dataset in Power Bi Service

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi

I see this message in 30 minutes after clicking Refresh-now-button (in Dataset tab):

```
Something went wrong
There was an error when processing the data in the dataset.

Please try again later or contact support. If you contact support, please provide these details.
Data source error: {"error":{"code":"ModelRefresh_ShortMessage_ProcessingError","pbi.error":{"code":"ModelRefresh_ShortMessage_ProcessingError","parameters":{},"details":[{"code":"Message","detail":{"type":1,"value":"Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation."}}],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}

Cluster URI: WABI-WEST-EUROPE-redirect.analysis.windows.net
Activity ID: 6465a7a0-8ee3-4f9b-bfae-d26800ff83b4
Request ID: 2a3851e0-5a38-3b96-783c-d0f5e1b464cb
Time: 2020-03-19 11:16:05Z

ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][BigQuery] (100) Error interacting with REST API: Operation timed out after 6.0 hours. Consider reducing the amount of work performed by your operation so that it can complete within this limit
```

Power Bi tries to refresh dataset 30 minutes, then shows this error. 
I use only Google BigQuery connection in my dataset.
I refreshed my data in BigQuery. Everything ok. It refreshes about 3-4 minutes.
I contacted with PowerBi support. Support-team told me, that problems with Google driver. And they can't help me...Until Google updates driver

Could someone help me?

Comment: Please check if the size of your dataset exceeds 1GB, if so, then try to reduce its size under 1GB and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few steps you need to check. Firstly, try to refresh credential for BigQuery to Power Bi and reduce the size of the data under 1GB.

I recommend to use Simba ODBC BigQuery Connector, which will eliminate the issue, please follow [this documentation](https://ittichaicham.com/2018/09/connect-power-bi-to-gcp-bigquery-using-simba-drivers/).

There is already a bug report on the issue tracker about it. I will let you know if there will be any updates.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I have 25Gb dataset. I'll try to reduce this amout.

Comment: Could you share a link report bug about the issue? 
Simba ODBC Connector is temporary expedient? Or i can use it constantly

Comment: Ok, let's try with data under 1GB and let me know. Here is the link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145895341